# SQL how can i detect if a value decrease over time?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: data base structure]

Hi, how can i check who are the employees whose salary has fallen ?

[image: sql result]:

```
SELECT employees.emp_no, first_name, last_name, salary, from_date, to_date, hire_date 
from employees
INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no;
```

I only want to fetch the name of employees whose salary has fallen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the positional analytic function `LAG()` to find these rows. This is a standard SQL function that peeks at a previous row, according to a specific criteria.

For example:

```
select emp_no, first_name, last_name
from (
  select
    e.*,
    s.salary,
    lag(s.salary) over(partition by e.emp_no order by from_date) as prev_salary
  from employees e
  join salaries s on s.emp_no = e.emp_no
) x
where salary < prev_salary
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using windowing functions.  It should look something like this:

```sql
with salary as (
    SELECT employees.emp_no, concat(first_name, " ",last_name) as emp, salary, coalesce(hire_date, from_date) as from_date, to_date
    from employees
        INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
), last_sal as (
    select emp_no, emp, salary, to_date, lag(salary) over (partition by emp_no, order by to_date) as last_salary
    from salary
)
select * 
from last_sal
where salary < last_salary
```

a windowing function basically takes a look at a subset of the data. In this case, the subset is of each employee, and then that window is ordered by `to_date`.  Lag tells it to look backwards, and effectively produces a row which has the prior row's salary result next to the current row for the other columns.